# RAML 1.0 Array of inner types

Tags: arrays, inline, raml

I have an api with two main resources : `Project` and `Product`, they are two differents resources with only a link between them.

```
Product:
  type: object
  properties:
    name: string
    projects: ProjectReference[]

ProjectReference:
  type: object
  properties:
    identifier: string
    links: Links[]

Project:
  type: object
  properties:
    identifier: string
    members: string[]
    product:
      type: object
      properties:
        name: string
        links: Link[]

Link:
  type: object
  properties:
    rel: string
    href: string
```

I would like to inline the `ProjectReference` type into `Product`. However, I have not found how to create array of inline types.

Can we create array of inline types with RAML 1.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what is the advantage of inlining....but you could do this:

```
Product:
  type: object
  properties:
    name: string
    projects:
      type: array
      items:
        type: object
        properties:
          identifier: string
          links: Links[]
```

Comment: The advantage is that I don't have to pollute my types with one that is never used alone and that I don't jave to invent stranges names to avoid clashes. Thanks